# Class C++ trace this value!

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class t
 {     public:
  int health; //its members
  int speed;
  int power;
  void attack() // its methods
{ cout<<"I'm attacking"<<endl;
  };
  };

int main()
{   t A,B,C,D;
A.power = 100;
B.health = 87;
C.speed = 92;
cout<<"A= "<<A.power<<"B= "<<A.health<<"C= "<<A.speed<<endl; // <---
cout<< "My health is "<<C.health<<" My speed is "<<A.speed<<endl;
cout<<"My power is "<<B.power<<endl;
D.attack();

system("pause");
return 0;}
```

---

The output result was ::
A= 100 B= 96 C=6234392 <--- From where these values come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a constructor to initialize those values to some default value in the initializer list.

```
class t {
public:
t() : health(100),power(100),speed(100) {}
// ...
};
```

This will guarantee that those values are all set to 100, or some default, or even an input parameter, rather than garbage. It's considered much better design since otherwise the initialization of those values would be handled in the constructor that the compiler generates for you behind the scenes.

Comment: Great! and the `{}` in `t() : health(100),power(100),speed(100) {}
` represents what?

Comment: Well t() is a function. It's the constructor for that class. So every time one of those classes are created, that function is called because that's the definition of a constructor. The `: health(100), power(100), speed(100)` is the "initialization list", and it initializes specified members of that class when it is called. The `{}` is the function definition. So you could put something in there like `std::cout << "constructor called!" << std::endl;`, and then every time the constructor is called, it would run that line. It's just a function, and that's the (empty) definition.

Answer (score 3):

`A.health` and `A.speed` are just junk values on the stack because you didn't explicitly set them. If you want to initialize all fields of `A` to zero, you can use `memset`:

```
memset(&A, 0, sizeof(A));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized memory?

Uninitialized variable won't be zero setted at the creation of the class/struct. You need to manualy do it. Otherwise, you will get whatever_is_in_memory_at_that_time.

Comment: i want to understand what the compiler do when it compiles `A.power = 100;` then `A.speed`. i know that `A` is just an object that represent the `t class`

Comment: What I was trying to say is that `A.power = 100` will affect the binary value of 100 to the power field of you instant A of type T. If you never initialize/affect any value to the `speed` member, than the only thing you can expect is to have a random value representing what ever is in memory at this exact point.